# When editing Drupal's .module files in Dreamweaver or Notepad++ how can I make the PHP code appear in different colors?

Tags: drupal, dreamweaver, notepad++

A simple usability question.  So I got a Dreamweaver 8 (I'm kinda used to it by now) and I've just downloaded Notepad++. (Before that I used simple Notepad) What I like about these editors is that the PHP code appears in different colors.  So if the colors are not right then you immediately know that you're doing something wrong.

But this works for only the files that end with **.php**

But Drupal's files end with **.module** and **.inc** etc... and it's often a nightmare to look for some comma or a single-quote that's messing up your code.   So how can I make Dreamweaver or Notepad++ to show me the code in .module and .inc files in colors?

Comment: http://vonlind.com/2008/06/dreamweaver-syntax-highlight-tip/

Answer (score 4):

in notepad++:

Settings > Style Configurator...

Find PHP  in the Language listing select it then add your desired extensions in the "User Ext :" field

leave the dot off and separate them with a space. you'll need to reopen the document after you save the change.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Drupal 'user language' for Notepad++ so you can get autocomplete and sytax highlighting:
Here is how to install in the last post here:
https://drupal.org/node/326803

Answer (score 0):

[image: My Favorite Nodepad++ Setup]

- Enable clickable links : Settings**->**Preferences**->**Misc**->**Enable clickable link
- Enable **PHP Syntax Highlighting** for .module files, .inc files and .install files by clicking Settings**->**Style Configurator**-> Click on the php extension in the left sidebar and copy and paste "*module inc install*" into the **user ext box** without the quotes of course and Save and close. Voila!